# Redirect Client in Java-Run Server

Tags: java, http, redirect

I am creating a Java HTTP server that checks to make sure a client is not banned before redirecting to the main server. I have already created everything for the server that is needed, I just don't know how to redirect to another port that is running the main server. Here is my code:

```
package netlyaccesscontrol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class AllowedCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = null;
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("Banned.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(80);
            Socket c = s.accept();
            String clientIP = c.getInetAddress().toString();
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)  {
                if (clientIP == line) {
                    s.close();
                } else {
                    // redirect to main server here
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("The banned IP address file does not exist.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirection that you are thinking of is something supported by HTTP and the browsers.  There's a specific HTTP response code that tells the caller to redirect and a way to specify it.

Raw sockets are a low-level network protocol that is not going to support redirection as you expect.  The most you might be able to do is have this program be a proxy and, upon success, push all incoming data/outgoing responses to/from the ultimate server.  But what you have here is by no means going to cut it.